# Alert if using Internet Explore

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to move my users away from IE. I want to display an alert if the user is using any version of IE to use Firefox or Chrome.  I have tried different methods of jQuery but nothing has worked.

Comment: Any particular version of IE? or just all IE. IE9 and 10 aren't that bad to code for. Doing this will more likely cause your users to move away from being your users rather than move away from IE

Comment: Was it seriously too difficult to google "how to tell if browser is IE"????

Comment: Try this: `<!--[if IE]><style>* {font-family: Comic Sans;}</style><![endif]-->`. This can be more effective than alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Conditional Comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
<!--[if IE ]>
<script LANGUAGE="javascript">
alert("Congratulations! You are running Internet Explorer");
</script>
```

But yes according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Important  As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode

Answer (score 4):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478303/correct-way-to-use-modernizr-to-detect-ie) will help you to detect the browser. It points out that while Modernizr will help you perform various browser specific actions, it will not help you detect the browser. It also shows how to do that.

Past that, if you are using jQuery and are willing to use jQuery UI, you can create a [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) which instructs the user that they are using IE and make recommendations on how and why they should migrate.

Perhaps this is beside the point, but as a web developer I consider supporting existing technology to be part of my job, and would be concerned about (at best) confusing and (at worst) insulting a user by telling them they should not use a particular browser.

Answer (score 1):

Check for this

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1)
{
    alert("You are using IE")
}
```