# Can I place IE conditionals in functions.php - WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-9

We are taught to place the following script in the `<head>` section, conditional to IE 9.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

As in WordPress I tend to use `wp_enqueue_script()` to hook scripts to `wp_head()` (default) or `wp_footer()`. My question is:

**(1)** can we implement something like the following in `functions.php` in WordPress theme?

```
function project_scripts(){?>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <?php
     wp_enqueue_script( 'IE-scripts', 'http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js' );
  ?>
  <![endif]-->
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'project_scripts' );
```

**(2)** If so, can I do it otherwise:

```
function project_scripts(){
  echo '<!--[if lt IE 9]>';
     wp_enqueue_script( 'IE-scripts', 'http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js' );
  echo '<![endif]-->';
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'project_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. JavaScript *cannot* include IE conditionals.

This is because IE conditional are *HTML comment nodes* and, just as normal HTML markup makes no sense in JavaScript source, such comments result in *invalid* JavaScript.

It may be worthwhile to look into an approach like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) which utilizes feature detection. Alternatively, IE conditional can be used to add classes to an element which can be detected later, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18630024/2864740).