# How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser on load javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to detect all browser (Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser) and show welcome message (like "welcome to opera") onload with javascript.

Comment: Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/ChristianL/AVyND/

Comment: have a look at something like http://faisalman.github.io/ua-parser-js/

Comment: Why do you want to do that? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478303/correct-way-to-use-modernizr-to-detect-ie. This might help: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser.

Answer (score 0):

hope this help you..

```
// Browser with version  Detection
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
    var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
    if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
    M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
    return M;
})();

var browser_version          = navigator.sayswho;
alert("Welcome to " + browser_version);
```

check out the working fiddle ( [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Harigr/u5aoLnuc/) )