# if IE10 or IE11 display different image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I need something like this:

```
<img src="image.svg" />

<!--[if IE ]><img src="image.png" /><![endif]-->
```

Since conditional comments are not working any more in IE10 and IE11 I'm having trouble accomplishing this.
Javascript that is available for targeting new internet explorer seems complicated and unreliable. But maybe I'm wrong and there is some simple solution.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Detecting this purely client side will be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: you are better off using styles and load in a different stylesheet for IE. Use a png fallback for unsupported browsers or use something like modenizr that adds classes to the `html` tag

Comment: I don't understand why this question deserves instant down vote. SVG works perfectly except on Internet Explorer. It renders this specific SVG incorrectly and it's logical to try to find a way how to replace it with PNG

Comment: Does the svg give an error in IE if it does not load? if so, you could just do `<img src="image.svg" onerror="this.src='image.png'" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will be hard to do without any scripts. And the answer given by @eisbehr will work great. But if you don't want to use any other plugins but jQuery, you can check [documentMode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_documentmode.asp) and add some info to body. Then let css decide what to show or not.

**NOTE**: it *doesn't work in Edge*. The code is written specifically for IE10 and IE11, since that's what the OP asked for. But it can be adjusted for different versions. But then I would go with the answer from @eisbehr instead.

```js
$(function() {
    if( document["documentMode"] ) { // If Internet Explorer 10, 11
        var cssClass = "ie" + document["documentMode"];
        $('body').addClass(cssClass);
    }
});
```

```css
.ie-dependant {
  display:none;
}

body.ie11 .ie-dependant.ie11 {
  display: block;
}

body.ie10 .ie-dependant.ie10 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ie-dependant ie10">
  This is ie 10.
</div>

<div class="ie-dependant ie11">
  This is ie 11.
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can detect this on server-side, and let the server return different stylesheets.

Answer (score 3):

Ther is no *build in* or default solution for this. You have to create own or use other tools. On browser side you could use tools like [`Modernizr`](https://modernizr.com/), [`browser`](https://github.com/ded/bowser) or [`jQuery.browser`](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.browser) and do a check with JS then.

```
if( browser.msie && browser.version >= 10 ) {
    // browser is IE10 or 11
}
```

Modernizer is even more complex and has a lot of possibilities. This could help you:

```
if( !Modernizr.svg ) {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var svgExtension = /.*\.svg$/
    var l = imgs.length;

    for( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
        if( imgs[i].src.match(svgExtension) ) {
            imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.slice(0, -3) + 'png';
        }
    }
}
```

Mode details about this example can be found [here](http://callmenick.com/post/svg-fallback-with-png).

Comment: I was just about to suggest Modernizr as well. :-) Seems like probably the most convenient way

Comment: Modernizr isn't used for detecting browser per say, but the capabilities the browser has. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478303/correct-way-to-use-modernizr-to-detect-ie https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/203

Comment: Thats why the modernizer example uses `!Modernizr.svg` to check svg compatibility and doesn't do a browser check. ;) @smoksnes

Comment: @eisbehr, Yes. Very clever. Thx for the edit BTW. Much cleaner.