# How to display a message when IE browser is opening?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a question and maybe it is duplicate in this site but i can't find it!

I want to display this message

`"Please open this website in firefox and you can download Mozilla Firefox from here"`

when users open my web in IE.

How do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display a Message When a Browser is Unsupported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348202/display-a-message-when-a-browser-is-unsupported)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348202/display-a-message-when-a-browser-is-unsupported

Comment: @Ravindra not necessary to post the same link again

Comment: What about Safari or Chrome?

Comment: @Barmar,it worked fine in Mozilla,Chrome and Safari but i want to recommend my users don't open it in IE!and there isn't a different between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer Javascript, you can check the userAgent.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')>0) {
    document.write('do something');
};
```

MSIE is the indicator for Microsoft Internet Explorer

Answer (score 2):

you can use a conditional check

```
<!--[if IE]>
please open this web in firefox and you can download Mozilla Firefox from <a href='here'>here</a>
<![endif]-->
```

or you could try adding a js/programming check