# How to Check if Browser is Outdated or IE and Display a banner

Tags: css, browser

how can i possibly detect if the browser used by a visitor is outdated or Internet explorer and display a banner at the of the page which will tell the visitor to upgrade its browser..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1GAk.png

Comment: possible duplacte of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348202/display-a-message-when-a-browser-is-unsupported

Comment: Outdated for what ? Html5 ?

Comment: Frankly, I would not do this...it's pretty rude. Perhaps the user CAN'T update or change browsers...some can't you know.

Comment: I know, but i have to because of the functionality of my site won't work on older browsers..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to detect if a browser support X or Y feature of HTML5 or CSS3, you have [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

you can generate a script [HERE](http://www.devslide.com/labs/browser-detection/configure) for detect just old browser and propose an upgrade

Comment: Much better.. THANKS !

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if lt IE x]>
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1GAk.png" alt="" />
<![endif]-->
```

You can use this code as it is. Replace x by IE version you want to "outdate".

Comment: Note that as of IE10 conditional comments are not supported and will always "return false", even `<!--[if IE]>`

Answer (score 0):

Here I found very sophisticated way to tell user about outdated-browsers:

- [outdatedbrowser.com](http://outdatedbrowser.com/)
- [project at GitHub](https://github.com/burocratik/outdated-browser)